# How to setup IIS 7 using physical path directing to DropBox?

Tags: iis, configuration, dropbox

I'm using multiple computers for development and I want to be able to store my files in my dropbox folder. I went to change the physical path in IIS from c:\inetpup\wwwroot to the dropbox folder but I get this error:

> The requested page cannot be accessed
>   because the related configuration data
>   for the page is invalid.

I couldn't find the config file so I was wondering if anyone had done this before or whether there a better way to sync everything nicely across several PCs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it (IIS 7.5, Win 7) and it should work just fine to let your physical path of your web look at your dropfox folder. I would guess your `web.config` file generally contains malformed XML ([see KB942055](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942055)).

I'd suggest, try to map it to an empty folder just with an `index.html` file and see if this error still occurs.

Comment: Do you have your DropBox folder in the default location?

Comment: No, I have it setup in a different directory.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I guess you can put Dropbox in your wwwroot folder and set up a virtual directory that points to Dropbox. However, there are some security issues that may hinder you from doing so. I come across a nice tutorial on how to set up Dropbox to IIS as FTP Publishing. Hope it helps.

[Hodgin's guide on using Dropbox as FTP publishing.](http://hodgin.ca/?p=405)